# Two Identical applications which communicate over a TCP socket connection on the localhost

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tcp

C#/XAML .NET WPF ... Both applications need to have the ability to connect with each other, and both should have listeners. How would I do this as I know that usually a TCP socket is client/server and what I need is basically two servers that act as clients? Is it possible?

Comment: If App1 = Server and App2 = client, then they can still both communicate to each other in both directions.

Comment: the server/client dichotomy really comes down to "who tries to connect to whom" - just... pick one? "server" doesn't mean "an installed service" or similar - it just means who listens for connections vs who tries to connect to someone who is listening. Once connected: the connection is full duplex - either can talk at any time

Comment: it's loopback... why tcp overhead? ... udp will work just fine...

Comment: I am being told that both application must have the same code. If one is a client and one is a server I believe that will be different

Comment: This is a project that was given to me. I realize there may be better ways to create, however that is not the case.

Comment: @MarcGravell I realize that once connected they will be able to communicate both ways. IS it possible to have two identical apps and that creates this or will there be differences?

Comment: It is perfectly possible. Have both instances listen for connections until one connects to the other. Once a connection is established both sides can stop listening as they now have a full duplex connection to one another.

Comment: I don't want to ofend you, but there is plenty documentation of this since Windows 3.11 and Visual 3, like... 30 years. This question seems to lack any kind of research.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm sorry there's no code for this answer. I'm not a C# developer (yet). I'm working on a very similar situation and it will be my first foray into the language.

For my scenario I need two copies of the same app to talk to one another but one of them will always start the connection first. It is a very basic game in which two players take turns. I can't hardcode IPs because they need to be able to talk even when not on localhost. My solution is:

1. One user selects "start game."
2. App one will open a socket and begin listening. This puts it in the role of server.
3. App one will then display the IP and Port #.
4. User two selects "join game"
5. User two enters the socket info provided.
6. App two will open a socket for sending, thus becoming the client.
7. Once the connection is fully established those sockets will be handed off to the code which handles the actual game play. This is possible because game play is identical for both parties regardless of who started.

For your scenario you can skip the displaying of the IP and Port. Both sides will begin listening and begin sending. Once a connection is established they can stop doing what isn't needed. i.e. if one successfully opens a client socket it stops listening as it no longer needs to be in the server role.